# Pushing data from Excel to Word throws error 5844 when text contains apostrophe

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, apostrophe

My Excel macro reads the values of a bunch of cells in Excel and pushes them to corresponding "content controls" in a Word template file. Everything works as planned unless the source cell contains a string with an apostrophe, e.g. "Children's Hospital". In this case execution stops:
"Run time error 5844    One of the values to this method or property is incorrect".
I have tried to read the cell value into an auxiliary string variable before assigning that to the content control but that did not help.
I also tried to force the source value to string using the CStr function - no good.
What do I do wrong?
Help please.

```
Sub PushToWord()
Dim oAppWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
  ...
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    ...
    oDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Institution").Item(1).Range.Text = .Cells(18, iSCol).Value
    ...
  End With
  ...
```

Comment: What type of content control is "Institution"?  Are you sure it's the apostrophe and not a newline that's the problem?  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6e801ca-2d12-4a66-8df4-734f15cf4333/linebreak-in-contentcontrol?forum=innovateonoffice

Comment: You could try checking the string first for curly or "smart" single quotes or apostrophes, then replace with a straight single quote. That's not causing any problems here in a quick test.

Comment: Tim, you nailed it. It was indeed not the apostrophe which caused the problem but a line break. Thank you!